# How to make this type of query in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

This is the sql query but how can I do it in laravel?

```
SELECT id FROM clientes where email is null and phone is null and id in(SELECT DISTINCT(cliente_id) FROM reservas WHERE dia < now())
```

This is the code that I tried to make:

```
$usersIdDel = DB::table("clientes")->select('id')
            ->whereNotNull('email')->whereNotNull('phone')
            ->whereIn('id',function($query){            $query->select('cliente_id')->from('reservas')->distinct()->where('dia','<',date('Y-m-d'));
            })
            ->get();
      $clientes = Cliente::select()->orderBy('nombre', 'desc')->get();
        return view('admin.clientes.index')->with(compact('clientes'));
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function! It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `... (SELECT DISTINCT cliente_id FROM ...` to make code clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two queries anyway so..

```
 $clientIds =  DB::table('reservas')->select('cliente_id')->distinct()->where('dia','<',date('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

then,

```
$usersIdDel = DB::table("clientes")->select('id')
        ->whereNotNull('email')->whereNotNull('phone')
        ->whereIn('id', $clientIds->pluck('cliente_id')->all())
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that without thinking about the complexity of converting or splitting queries to multiple query builder statements.

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM clientes where email is null and phone is null and id in(SELECT DISTINCT(cliente_id) FROM reservas WHERE dia < now())";
$result = DB::select($sql);
```